# When I create a Python function to merge two dataframes and feed in values individual, it works. But when I do a loop, I get a key error

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, for-loop, merge, keyerror

I created this function:

```
def designate(people,race):
    global i2
    global clilaw
    i2=i2.sort_values(by=people)
    i2=pd.merge(i2,clilaw,how='left',left_on=people,right_on='category')
    i2[race]=i2['race']
```

When I feed in values individually, it works.

```
designate(prl[1],race2[1])
designate(prl[2],race2[2])
...
designate(prl[12],race2[12])
```

But when I try to create a loop to do it, like this:

```
for k in range(len(prl)):
    designate(prl[k],race2[k])
```

I get a key error:

```
KeyError: 'race'
```

Answer (score 1):

`range(len(prl))` is `[0, 1, \dots, len(prl)-1`. 
In the for loop you are trying to access `designate(prl[0], race2[0])` and so on but when you feed the values manually you start from `1`. Could that be the problem? If so try `range(1, len(prl)+1)`.

Answer (score 0):

I understand now. Each time the merging is done, different race columns (race_x, race_y) are created so during the next iteration, i2['race'] isn't recognized.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that concatenates two dataframes. Use previously created function to create
two dataframes and pass them as parameters Make sure that the indexes are reset before
returning:

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).